# ntbackup crash corruption

Tags: backup, ntbackup

I want to backup my domain using differential backup on ntbackup, question is what if my computer crashes in the middle of the backup, would that corrupt my previous one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.  A failed differential backup does not invalidate your previous backup.

A differential is a backup of all the files that have changed since the last full backup.  So as long as you still have your last full backup, plus your previous incremental, you're ok.

Comment: Question is, whether on not ntbackup puts the last backup into a invalid state while backuping (because it is done every day, into the same file), and if a crash would keep that file in that state, or does it create a different backup file and then swap the two?

Comment: oh. your appending to the same file? You'd have to test that i guess.  Why can't you backup to a new bkf file each time to avoid the problem?